# Multi style sheet with jQuery cookies (Issue with pop up box)

Tags: jquery, html, cookies, popup

```
$(function() {
    $('#yes a').click(function() {
        $.cookie('AutoPlayTrue', '1', {
            expires: 999
        });
        $('.disableAutoPlay').hide('slow');
        $.cookie('ccss_remembered_style', null);
        $.cookie('AutoPlayFalse', null);
    });
    $('#ccss-no a').click(function() {
        $.cookie('AutoPlayFalse', '1', {
            expires: 999
        });
        $('.disableAutoPlay').hide('slow');
        $.cookie('AutoPlayTrue', null);
    });
    if ($.cookie('AutoPlayFalse') === null) {
        $('.disableAutoPlay').show();
    }
    else {
        $('.disableAutoPlay').hide();
    }

    if ($.cookie('AutoPlayTrue') === null) {
        $('.disableAutoPlay').show();
    }
    else {
        $('.disableAutoPlay').hide();
    }
});
```

I have a pop up box with the HTML:

```
<li class="widget ccss" id="ccss-widget-3"><h2 class="widgettitle">Should HipHop97.com Automatically Start Playing Music?</h2>
    <ul id="ccss-list">

        <li id="ccss-no"><a href="http://hiphop97.com/wp-content/themes/hiphop/noAutoPlayCSS.css">No</a></li><li id="yes"><a href="#">Yes</a></li>
    </ul>

</li>
```

I need when the 'yes' button is selected just act as a 'close' and with cookies 'don't show me again' and the 'no' button I've already got the style sheet and stuff code worked out I just need it to not display the box again with cookies. (The element is in the theme, just marked as `display:none;` it's at the top of the main container.)

I tried this, it's a good concept I suppose, it just doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if ($.cookie('AutoPlayFalse')) {
        $('.displayAutoPlay').css('display','none !important');
    }
    if ($.cookie('AutoPlayTrue')) {
        $('.displayAutoPlay').css('display','none !important');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I would recommend you do not use auto play this would drive people mad trying to find out where the music [sound] coming from, and when they do, they will never visit your website or simply close the window down, but it is up to you. People are not lazy a click of a button to play something it is user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!$.cookie('autoplay')){
   //display box
}else{
   $.cookie('autoplay',1);
}
```

I dont understand why do you over complicate it as much :)